# Capture citation of google scholar

Tags: r, rvest

I want to capture te citation of one article as is showed in google scholar, as showed in the image:

[image: the cite exist, as showed in 1]

The citation exist, as showed in 1. But It is necesary a click to obrtain a frame that shows the citation.

I can have accees to the search trough R in This way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
getGoogleURL <- function(search.term, domain = '.com', quotes=FALSE) 
{
  search.term <- gsub(' ', '%20', search.term)
  if(quotes) search.term <- paste('%22', search.term, '%22', sep='')
  getGoogleURL <- paste('https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=',
                        search.term, sep='')
}

google.url <- getGoogleURL("GARZA, Sergio Francisco de la, Derecho financiero mexicano, México, Porrúa, 2002.")

doc <- read_html(google.url)
doc %>% html_elements( "b") %>% html_text()
```

How I can get the citation?

Comment: You might try `rvest::follow_link()` to “click” the citation button. If that doesn’t work, you may have to try RSelenium.

Comment: A good tutorial for that?. I have edited my post to make it a reproductible example